# Given a webView, how to change the URL in a different class file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using Macgap: https://github.com/maccman/macgap/issues/34

In the Notice.m class would the ability to change the webview's URL. I'm trying the following but getting errors:

```
[self.contentView.webView setMainFrameURL:[self.url @"https://google.com"]];
```

Suggestions to point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

setMainFrameURL expects a string as parameter, [self.url @"https://google.com"] has no sense, the following will be better:

```
[self.contentView.webView setMainFrameURL:@"https://google.com"];
```

Also, the Notice class is not the right place to do it, maybe WindowController, but I don't know what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks but I get the error, property 'contentView' not found on object of type Notice

Comment: How can I access the webView from the notice.m class? Thanks

Comment: The notice class is intended to manage the user notifications, it would be wrong to force an url from there.

Comment: I'm new to this, suggestions on how I should approach. Pointer in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think I mentioned in the Q? Can I provide additional details? Just let me know thanks